# Undo the Git remote branch checkout

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I was suppose to copy files on my CentOS 7 machine from a remote branch of git repo. I created a new folder at incorrect location and clone the repo. After this I have checkout the remote branch also.

I did following steps: 1. Git Clone ( Worked fine)
                       2. Git Checkout branch name ( worked fine)

Unfortunately, I noticed that I was suppose to create folder at different location and clone the files into that folder then checkout and work on those files. Now my question :

1. How can I undo the checkout of this branch currently ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, But if I understand your question correctly. You want to move everything to a different location.

So, first of all there is no concept of undoing any checkout. When you checkout to a different branch in git. It just points your HEAD to another commit. That's it. So, if you want to move back to the `master` branch (Which is a default branch in most of the cases) you just need to do `git checkout master`.

But I think the problem for you is not related to git here, What you want to achieve is move the folder at some other place.
So IMO, you just need to move the folder to new location.

```
mv /incorrect/user/path/FOLDER /correct/folder/path/FOLDER
```

And now when you change the working directory to the newly placed folder, git will work fine regardless.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: as a small addition, in the original checkout folder there is a hidden .git folder. This holds the git specific details. As suggested above, mv will include .git so nothing extra needed. But fyi to give you some more understanding https://githowto.com/git_internals_git_directory

Comment: Thank you so much both of you for help. I got answer of my question.